# Easily producing Python AST for multiple expressions in one line

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I'd like to recreate this expression with Python AST:

```
1 == 2; 1 >= 2
```

And I can achieve this with the following AST structure:

```
Module(
    body=[
        Expr(value=Compare(left=Num(n=1), ops=[Eq()], comparators=[Num(n=2)])),
        Expr(value=Compare(left=Num(n=1), ops=[GtE()], comparators=[Num(n=2)]))
    ]
)
```

But the above AST structure is identical for 2 expression in a single line and 2 expressions, each in a separate line.

I know that I can *manually* calculate and modify the nodes' `col_offset` and `lineno` attributes to make it a signle line expression, but is there an easier way?

Comment: Are you trying to produce the AST from the source code, or the source code from the AST? What dissatisfies you about the AST you have?

Comment: I'm trying produce an AST structure which I can the compile and run. The AST I have will produce the equivalent of:
`
1 == 2
1 >= 2
`
rather than the one liner

Comment: Is there a difference in the compiled code between the one and two-line versions?

Comment: @noamt: What's wrong with `ast.parse`, then?

Comment: Why do you care about how many lines these expressions are spread across, anyway? If you have source code, you can just `ast.parse` it, and if you don't have source code, you don't really have lines, either, so you might as well fill in dummy values for all the `col_offset`s and `lineno`s.

Comment: An AST models the logical content, not the physical line layout. That the AST contains line and column numbers still is a token nod towards rewriting usecases where people want to alter existing code. If you are not generating the AST from existing source, then you are stuck with calculating the line and column info yourself.

Comment: I can imagine caring about column offsets and line numbers when creating code rewriting tools that try to maintain the user's formatting as much as possible. It also might matter for ascii art, polyglots, minifying, code golf, etc. I'm curious what @noamt needed it for.

Comment: @AlexVagra I'm taking a shot at writing a testing a Python testing framework that's heavily inspired by Groovy's Spock framework. It's still a WIP - https://github.com/browncoat-ninjas/nimoy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you've generated the AST by some method other than directly parsing the code. One simple solution might be to

1. convert all or parts of the AST back to a string of python code
2. manipulate that string
3. `parse()` the result

to get a new effectively equivalent AST with new *correct* line numbers and column offsets.

For example, walk the full AST, and for every `body`, convert it to python code, replace all newline characters with semicolons, `parse()` the result, and replace the original body with the result.

**Edit:** Here's a simple demo using the [astunparse](https://github.com/simonpercivall/astunparse) module:

```
from ast import *
from astunparse import *

a1 = parse("1 == 2\n1 >= 2")
print map(lambda x: (x.lineno, x.col_offset), a1.body)  # [(1, 0), (2, 0)]

a2 = parse(unparse(a1).strip().replace('\n', ';'))
print map(lambda x: (x.lineno, x.col_offset), a2.body)  # [(1, 0), (1, 9)]
```